# How to change one value equal to another in an int array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make the code so it wont print the same number twice or more. I have no clue how to make it that way. what do I need to change/add to make it print only one of each number?

```
public class LottoSpill {
public static int ran() {
    int random = (int)(Math.random()*34+1);
    return random;
}

public static int lottoRekke() {
    int[] array = {ran(), ran(), ran(), ran(), ran(), ran(), ran()};
    int ret = array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++){
            if(array[i] == array[j]) {
                array[i] = array[i] - array[j] + ran();
                do {
                j++;
                i++;
                } while(i < array.length || j < array.length);
                for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
                    System.out.print(array[k] + " ");
                }
            }  else if(array[i] != array[j]) {
                do { 
                    j++;
                    } while(j < array.length);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    lottoRekke();
}
```

}

this is the result of the code, as you can see the number 17 have been printed twice

25 10 17 20 17 6 27 [Finished in 0.3s]

Comment: Please don't post images of code or output. Copy them into your post and format them appropriately.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: sorry I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: @BigApe no problem.  Just copy paste your code.  Put it between a pair of three back ticks `\`\`\`` which are on separate lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

- Generate a List of the numbers from 1 to 34. (or whatever your range is).

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 34; i++) {
  list.add(i);
}
```

- then call Collections.shuffle() on the list.

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

- then just take the first 6 (or however many) numbers.  They will be random and unique.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

**EDIT**

You can pass the starting and ending numbers or leave them out and hard code them in the method.

```
public static List<Integer> lottery(int start, int end) {
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        nums.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(nums);
    return nums;
}

// e.g.
List<Integer> vals = lottery(1,34);
```

Comment: It worked thanks :), but do you know how to make this as a method? I tried, but don't know what to put as a return value

Comment: What do you want to return?  An array of int[] with the values? What are you trying to compute?

Comment: I want to return the hole array, and is it possible to do this with an array of int[]?